# Lost connection to MySQL server at ‘reading initial communication packet’

Tags: mysql, freebsd

I am using FreeBSD 9.2 and mysql 5.5 and i am using **SOMETIMES** this error - * Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0* when i am executing sql commands from outside (localhost works fine).
I have been googling almost whole day.
....
I have tryed:

mysqld : ALL : allow  -> hosts.allow

bind-address with-my-live-server-ip -> my.cnf

commenting bind-address in my.cnf

and allowingtcpforwarding in sshd_config

help me please...

Comment: and i am not using any firewall

Comment: Since you are not using a firewall please include that information in the question, rather than as a comment.  Additionally, provide the contents your `my.cnf` configuration.  Take a look at `dmesg` and your server logs to see if anything of note is in there and include that in your question as well.

Comment: Regarding this statement: "`and allowingtcpforwarding in sshd_config`".  Are you tunneling your mysql connection through SSH?  If so please provide the steps you're using to do this.

Comment: Increase connect_timeout global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `show global status;`, look for the `Aborted_connections` and `Threads_created`, if both values are high increase the `thread_cache_size` variable.